# Чтение данных из excel

Tags: c#, winforms

Нашёл на просторах StackOverflow пример как читать данные из excel. Но вылетают ошибки. Не пойму что делаю не так.
Вот код:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbConnection MyConnection;
            DataSet DtSet;
            OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;

            MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='D:\file.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
            MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Лист1$]", MyConnection);
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net");
            DtSet = new DataSet();
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
            MyConnection.Close();
        }
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Объект 'Лист1$' не найден ядром
>   базы данных Microsoft Jet.  Проверьте существование объекта и
>   правильность имени и пути.'

Так как у меня 10 офис. Меняю на тип xlsx. Тогда вылетает вот такая вот ошибка:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Внешняя таблица не имеет
>   предполагаемый формат.'

Пробовал даже с пустым файликом. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Рекомендую [ExcelDataReader](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) , [https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader)

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev спасибо, но хотелось бы для начала разобраться почему не хочет в таком виде работать.

Comment: можете поделиться screenshot excel'a?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev могу конечно, но если даже с пустым такая же ошибка. Этого не достаточно?)